# How to reduce gigantic TFRecord size caused by repetitive keys

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, tfrecord

Since my input json is a few GB in size which takes a long time to parse I decided to try and turn it into more efficient (or so I thought) TFRecord files. Long story short, by doing that I inflated my dataset by **10x**...

When I took a closer look at some of my generated tfrecord files I saw that for each protobuf Example **all** the keys for every single input feature were included. Since I have 130 (fairly verbose) keys and a few million examples the majority of disk space is now used up by those repetitive keys. Clearly there must be a better way than repeating keys for every Example.
Here is my code

```
        for i in zip(inputs, labels):
            features = dict()
            for j in zip(self.getKeys(), i[0]):
                features[j[0]] = tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[j[1].encode()]))
            features['label'] = tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=i[1]))

            # Create an example protocol buffer
            example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=features))
            # Writing the serialized example.
            writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
```

I found the documentation regarding TFRecords very lacking so I'm asking here:
How can I efficiently save my data using TFRecords? Is it possible to save by feature and not by example? That way I would only have to include the key name once per feature.

Comment: You can compress TFRecord data using GZIP or ZLIB.

Comment: Sure, I could fight the symptoms using compression but I'd rather get to the root of the problem which is the inefficient saving of the keys. I feel that, if anything, TFRecords are making my life more difficult, not easier as promised. :-/